# React Native Context not re-rendering when value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state, react-context

I'm trying to make a login page and system with React and I'm using Context. I'm using a value 'userId' as the key to change between two navigators, the 'AuthNav' which is in charge of the Login page and the SignUp page and the 'AppNav' which has the rest of the App. Here's my Context:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { Alert } from "react-native";

export const AppContext = React.createContext(true);

export function Context({ children }) {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  /**
   * The Lists variable is an array of productList which the list that is shown in the MyListScreen
   * Form -> [{key, name, list:[{ id, product:{name, quantity, quantityType, price}, buy: boolean }] }]
   */
  const [Lists, setLists] = useState([]);

  /**
   * Visibility of the modal
   */
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  //don't forget to add the Login properties

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        await isLoggedIn();
        await checkLists();
        console.log("Context -> Lists' length: " + Lists.length);
        console.log("Context -> Lists: " + JSON.stringify(Lists));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log("Context -> useEffect: userId: " + userId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Context -> Login changed: " + userId);
  }, [userId]);

  //For the Login
  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      setisLoading(true);
      let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userId");
      setUserId(userToken);
      setisLoading(false);
      return 0; // Success
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in line 24 Context.js", error);
      return 1; // Error
    }
  };

  const login = async (userId) => {
    try {
      setisLoading(false);
      setUserId(JSON.stringify(userId));
      AsyncStorage.setItem("userId", "mamammamama");
      console.log("Context -> userId: " + userId);
      return 0; // Success
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("handleSignupError in login:", error);
      return 1; // Error
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      setisLoading(true);
      setUserId(null);
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userId");
      setisLoading(false);
      console.log("Context -> Logged out: " + userId);
      return 0; // Success
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in logout:", error);
      return 1; // Error
    }
  };

........
........

return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        userId,
        isLoading,
        login,
        logout,
        Lists,
        saveLists,
        addProduct,
        removeItem,
        saveProductList,
        toggleCheck,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and in the LoginScreen

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import InputField from "../Components/InputField";
import Button from "../Components/Generic/Button";
import { AppContext } from "../Contexts/Context";
import { ScaledSheet } from "react-native-size-matters";
import genericStyles from "../Styles/genericStyles";

/**
 * The login screen component.
 *
 * @param {Object} navigation - The navigation object provided by React Navigation.
 * @returns {JSX.Element} The login screen UI.
 */
export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const { login } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const [lgin, setLgin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lgin) {
      login("mama");
      setLgin(false);
    }
  }, [lgin]);

  /**
   * Checks if an email is valid using a regular expression.
   *
   * @param {string} email - The email to validate.
   * @returns {boolean} True if the email is valid, false otherwise.
   */
  function isValidEmail(email) {
    const emailRegex =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return emailRegex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  }

  /**
   * Handles the login action. Validates input and attempts to log in.
   */
  const handleSignup = () => {
    if (!email || !password) {
      alert("Please fill out all the fields");
    } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid email address");
    } else {
      setLgin(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.centeredContainer}>
        <View style={styles.centered}>
          <Image
            source={require("../Assets/Images/Logos/discountlogo.png")}
            style={styles.logo}
          />
        </View>

        <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>

        {/* Email Input */}
        <InputField
          label={"Email"}
          icon={
            <Ionicons name="at" size={20} color="#666" style={styles.icon} />
          }
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setEmail(text);
          }}
        />

        {/* Password Input */}
        <InputField
          label={"Password"}
          inputType={"password"}
          icon={
            <Ionicons
              name="lock-closed-outline"
              size={20}
              color="#666"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          }
          onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        />

        <Button
          label={"Login"}
          onPress={handleSignup}
          addStyles={styles.loginButton}
        />
        <Text style={styles.centerText}>Or, login with ...</Text>

....
....
```

when I click on the Login button having already introduced any valid email and a password, the Context doesn't re-render this component. Which changes between the Navigators

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppContext, Context } from "../Contexts/Context";
import AppStack from "../Navigation/AppStack";
import AuthStack from "../Navigation/AuthStack";

function AppNav() {
  const { userId } = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UserId in useEffect:", userId);
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <Context>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {userId ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Context>
  );
}

export default AppNav;
```

What do you think it could be the problem?

I've tried using the 'useEffect' to check the behaviours of the userId in different components and it results that the value changes in the Context but the 'AppNav'(the switcher between navigators) doesn't re-render.

I've discovered that when I forcefully re-render(by clicking ctrl+s in the editor) the AppNav file, it doesn't switch, but when I forcefully re-render the Context file it switches the navs(it does what I want it to do), but if I leave it on its own and then I click on the logIn button and the value of UserId changes, it doesn't re-render on its own. :(

Answer (score 0):

This ist just a guess but maybe use use focus instead of `useEffect`

```js
  useFocus(() => { // useEffect
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        await isLoggedIn();
        await checkLists();
        console.log("Context -> Lists' length: " + Lists.length);
        console.log("Context -> Lists: " + JSON.stringify(Lists));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log("Context -> useEffect: userId: " + userId);
  }, []);
```

Or add `userId` to your dependency array

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        await isLoggedIn();
        await checkLists();
        console.log("Context -> Lists' length: " + Lists.length);
        console.log("Context -> Lists: " + JSON.stringify(Lists));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching data: ", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log("Context -> useEffect: userId: " + userId);
  }, [userId]);
```

Comment: thank you for your response. As I searched, useFocus is only usable when the component is visible I need the context to re-render a component without having consideration if it's visible or not.
And for your second answer, I've tried the useEffect with the [userId] in the line underneath the one that you modified.